# How to create a recylerview inside a recylerview item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a NotesApp and I have a recylerview which is shown in my Activity called NotesActivity, when I click on a recylerview item it opens up another Activity called Classwork (which have another recyclerview in it). The idea is to create assignment lists inside each note (recyclerview item)

The problem is when I create an assignment it is shown in the NotesActivity instead of ClassworkActivity. I created an Adapter and a Listdata for each of those 2 recylerviews

This is what I tried:

**NotesAdapter.java**

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.MyHolder> {

    List<Listdata> noteslist;
    private Context context;
    public  NotesAdapter(List<Listdata> noteslist,Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        this.noteslist=noteslist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);

        MyHolder myHolder=new MyHolder(view);
        return myHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, final int position) {
        final Listdata data=noteslist.get(position);
        myHolder.title.setText(data.getTitle());
        myHolder.desc.setText(data.getDesc());
        myHolder.menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, myHolder.menuIcon);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_edit:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i=new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("id",data.id);
                                i.putExtra("title",data.title);
                                i.putExtra("desc",data.desc);
                                context.startActivity(i);
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_delete:
                                noteslist.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteslist.size();
    }


    class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView title,desc;
        ImageView menuIcon;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            menuIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Listdata listdata=noteslist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent i=new Intent(context, StreamActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                    i.putExtra("title",listdata.title);
                    i.putExtra("desc",listdata.desc);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });


        }

    }

}
```

**AssignmentAdapter.java**

```
public class AssignmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AssignmentAdapter.MyHolder>  {

    private List<AssignListdata> assignmentlist;
    private Context context;
    public  AssignmentAdapter(List<AssignListdata> assignmentlist, Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        this.assignmentlist=assignmentlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AssignmentAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.assignment_item,viewGroup,false);

        AssignmentAdapter.MyHolder myHolder=new AssignmentAdapter.MyHolder(view);
        return myHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AssignmentAdapter.MyHolder myHolder, final int position) {


        final AssignListdata data=assignmentlist.get(position);
        myHolder.titleas.setText(data.getTitle());
        myHolder.descas.setText(data.getDesc());




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return assignmentlist.size();
    }


    class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView titleas,descas;
        ImageView menuIcon;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleas=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_as);
            descas=itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_as);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AssignListdata listdata=assignmentlist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent i=new Intent(context, EditAssignActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                    i.putExtra("title",listdata.titleas);
                    i.putExtra("desc",listdata.descas);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

**AssignListdata.java** (for the Assignment List which supposed to be created inside each note)

```
public class AssignListdata {

    public String getTitle() {
        return titleas;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.titleas = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return descas;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.descas = desc;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String id;
    public String titleas;
    public String descas;

    public AssignListdata() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public AssignListdata(String id,String title, String desc) {
        this.id=id;
        this.titleas = title;
        this.descas = desc;

    }
}
```

**Listdata.java** (for the Notes)

```
public class Listdata {

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String desc;

    public Listdata() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public Listdata(String id,String title, String desc) {
        this.id=id;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;

    }

}
```

and you can find in this link, my other files (especially the Add and Edit activities): [my Add and Edit activities](https://github.com/XLogger-g/Recyclerview-test)